# Share Cassandra cluster/session in Akka model

Tags: java, cassandra, akka, cassandra-2.0

I'm facing a memory leak problem in Cassandra driver. After check the out of memory heap error, I can see there's a warning saying that I'm creating more than one cluster/session per phisical cluster, and I should not. Since in my Akka configuration I have a maximum of 32, I can imagina that I'm creating 32 cluster/sessions instance, and most probably I'm forcing the memory leak.

My question now is. How can I share just one instance of cluster/session of Cassandra between the actors without break the inmutable actor paradigm of Akka?

Regards

Comment: I'm in java, but even if I put Cluster and sessions static, it won't break the inmutable actor state dogma of Akka? That's the reason of my question. I was thinking to use instead Akka agent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a singleton (e.g., a class you know is instantiated just once at your end-of-the-world bootstrap) and pass that in `Props` when constructing your actors.

```
object Main extends App {
   val services = new Services
   // ...
   val actor1 = system.actorOf(Props(classOf[MyActor], services), "actor1")
   val actor2 = system.actorOf(Props(classOf[MyActor], services), "actor2")
}

class Services {
   val cassandraSession = ??? // ... however you create it
}
```

You could also just create a Cassandra session from an `object` and refer to that, but it's generally less testable.

The example code is Scala, but the same approach applies in Java.

Comment: I'm afraid is not that easy, we're initializing actor in a very old fashion way with spring. But I get your idea. Thanks. Anyway is the idea of use Agent worst?

Comment: Avoid agents because as per http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/agents.html 
"Agents have been deprecated and are scheduled for removal in the next major version"

Comment: Good to know, thanks. Are you suggesting any other solution?

Comment: @paul You could also just create the actor the way you are doing it and pass the singleton immediately after starting the actor(as suggested by John) using a tell and then set it in the receive method.

Comment: You could also just store the session in a singleton / static object (in Java it would be a static field of a class) and refer to that from the Actor. I don't like this practice as it is poorly testable (therefore I pass the Services in the actor Props), but it is an option.

@paul please accept the answer if it's OK.

Comment: @JohnM I´m gonna wait to see if someone else suggest something else. Use statics in Akka is anti patter since actors are stateless. I gave your vote for sure ;)

Comment: Actors are not stateless. Many actors are used exactly to encapsulate shared state..

Comment: When I said they are stateless is because they have a lifecycle where they bord do a task and die, just like a thread, and everything that happens there is thread-local and they dont share state. https://manuel.bernhardt.io/2016/08/02/akka-anti-patterns-shared-mutable-state/